# how to select the column based on column names stored in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dfs, which part of df1 is shown below [1101 rows x 139 columns]

```
             GP9       VWF      ALOX12    C1orf198    MPL     PTGS1  
0           2.884147  2.189103  1.323701  1.411450  6.615392  5.637339
1           4.788212  0.434247  1.449879  1.313428  7.236131  5.770543
2           1.710748  3.370917  2.798043  1.531801  6.318867  5.261016
3           2.030750  4.599848  2.312753  2.626536  6.296336  5.823157
4           0.615780  3.480914  2.158669  1.939806  6.108159  6.000171
5           1.015158  2.282270  1.207885  1.630455  6.516448  5.638960
```

And the dataframe header is stored in anther dataframe df2, part of df2 is shown below [135 rows x 2 columns]

```
           P_value   gene_name
1     2.640666e-15         GP9
2     1.996181e-40         VWF
3     1.908219e-05      ALOX12
4     4.463029e-69    C1orf198
5     5.747815e-43         MPL
6     7.470865e-03       PTGS1
7     3.774896e-34        SELP
8     2.246091e-66      ITGA2B
9     1.146707e-53       ABCC3
```

I have calculated P value of those gene df2, for p value less than 0.05 means this gene is important for my further study. So I need to filter those gene out from df1.

Anyone knows how to select the columns in df1 from the gene names indicated in df2? Thanks

Comment: can you be more specific about your problem? as I can see you already have same column names from gene_name. Why you want to select these gene_name?

Comment: Because I have calculated P value of those gene, for p value less than 0.05 means this gene is important for my further study. So I need to filter those gene out from df1.

Comment: Edit your question with expected output so we can help you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df2.loc[df2['P_value'].lt(0.05), 'gene_name']
```

returns the gene names for those that satisfy your p value criterion. You can use this list to select columns from `df1`:

```
df1[df2.loc[df2['P_value'].lt(0.05), 'gene_name']]
```

This will raise a KeyError if `df2` has additional gene names that do not appear in df1. If that's the case, use intersection:

```
df1[df1.columns.intersection(df2.loc[df2['P_value'].lt(0.05), 'gene_name'])]
```

or

```
df1[df1.columns & (df2.loc[df2['P_value'].lt(0.05), 'gene_name'])]
```

Answer (score 0):

First select column names which have P_value less than 0.5

```
cols = list(df2[df2['P_value'] < 0.05]['gene_name'])
```

Then filter out the columns from df1

```
df_new = df1[cols]
```